How to Get a Dynamically Generated Pivot via SQL?
Input
This is the table I already have.

The columns Date and State together constitute composite primary keys. Assume we have a few months of daily data from all 50 states.
What I want
A pivoted view like this, where Date is the primary key.

Some query snippets I have seen (example below), seem to use hardcoded group-by for each value of the pivot column (State), which seems not scalable to fifty states. Depending on the problem, there may even be even more values than fifty when its definitely not feasible.
SELECT 
    start_dt, 
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN state = 'NY' THEN sales ELSE 0 END
    ) AS NY, 
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN state = 'CA' THEN sales ELSE 0 END
    ) AS CA, 

  FROM 
    sales_raw
  GROUP BY 
    start_dt; 

So what's the SQL way of doing this without hardcoding?
Dialect
If relevant, I am using Google big query. So best if any function in a hypothetical solution is available in BQ.

Post the query that you're using currently.

Which dbms are you using? The solution might use product specific functionality.

Or do a basic GROUP BY, and fix the presentation in an above layer.

@jarih Google Big Query. What do you mean by fix the presentation in an above layer?
